# MobX React: How to only Re-render part of View

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, google-maps-react

I have a map react component and I'm dynamically adding markers.The problem is that when I add markers in the store, the whole map rerenders instead of just appending the markers to the map. Has anyone got any suggestions on how this could be fixed?? I'm pretty sure that I need to Inject the store into CPMap function exclusively, I'm just not sure how.

```
const CPMap = withGoogleMap((props) => (
        <GoogleMap
            ref={props.onMapLoad}
            style={{
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
            }}
            onCenterChanged={props.boundsChanged}
            defaultOptions={{ styles: this.mapStyles }}
            defaultZoom={props.zoom}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: props.center.lat, lng: props.center.lng }}>
            <MarkerClusterer
                gridSize={40}>
                {
                    props.markers.map(({ key, position }) => (
                        <Marker
                            key={key}
                            position={{ lat: position.lat, lng: position.lng }}
                            icon={{
                                url: require('../../images/marker.png')
                            }}
                        />
                    ))
                }
            </MarkerClusterer>
        </GoogleMap >
    ))

    return (
        <CPMap
            style={{
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
            }}
            onMapLoad={(gMap) => {
                map = gMap
                this.props.map.fetchMarkers()
            }}
            boundsChanged={() => {
                this.props.map.fetchMarkers()
            }}
            center={this.props.map.center}
            zoom={this.props.map.zoom}
            markers={mobx.toJS(this.props.map.markers)}
            containerElement={
                <div style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 70px)' }
                } />
            }
            mapElement={
                <div style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 70px)' }} />
            } />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose you the following solution: don't pass makers directly to CMap component, but use store instead;

```
const markersStore = observable({
    markers: []
});
```

Then in your component - move MarkersClusterer to the separate component and pass markersStore one level deeper:

```
//import markersStore or inject via mobx-react package
class MyComponent extends Component {
   render() {
      const CMap = withGoogleMap((props) => (
         <GoogleMap
            ...
            <Clusterer markersStore={props.markersStore} />
         />
      ))
      return (
         <CMap
            ...
            markersStore={markersStore}
         />
      )
   }
}
```

Make your new Cluster component observable so it updates when markersStore "markers" property updates;

```
@observable
class Clusterer extends Component {
    render(){
       const { markers } = this.props.markersStore;
       return (
          <MarkerClusterer>
              { markers.map(...)}
          </MarkerClusterer>
       )
    }
}
```

The final change is to update your fetchMarkers method so it populates the markersStore with new data.

With this solution CMap component doesn't know anything about markers and it doesn't updates when new data received. At the same time MarkersClusterer component becomes more clever and "observes" changes in the markersStore.